# Problema ao importar um projeto .net framework para um projeto .net core

Tags: c#, .net, exceção, .net-core

olá, eu estou criando um aplicação .net core mas preciso utilizar um projeto em .net framework.
eu consigo importa-lo sem erro algum mas em tempo de execução é disparado um exceção.

[image: img]

A Exceção diz que não foi possível carregar System.Web.Services, mas quando eu estava testando o sistema no .net framework não disparava essa exceção.

eu tentei importa-lo de duas maneiras:

-A mais simples importando dll do projeto.

-A mais demorar por que me indicaram eu criei o projeto .net framework dentro da minha solução e importei o projeto para o outro.

Aqui é o Issues que havia aberto no git do projeto que importei [link](https://github.com/ZeusAutomacao/DFe.NET/issues/959)

Comment: Qual erro ocorreu quando tentou importar a DLL? O que esse projeto faz num geral?

Comment: ao importar o projeto não ocorre erro algum, o erro acontece somente em tempo de execução.

Comment: o Projeto que eu estou importando é o Zeus.
https://github.com/ZeusAutomacao/DFe.NET

Comment: Pelo que li aqui (https://github.com/ZeusAutomacao/DFe.NET) esse projeto *Atualmente utiliza o .NetFramework na versão 4.5*. .Net Core não é compatível com .NetFramework 4.5